# Uniform continuity of $\sin x$ on open interval

Tags: real-analysis

I know that $\sin(x)$ is uniformly continuous over $(0,\infty)$ but it seems counterintuitive to me since the limit at the endpoint $(\infty)$ won’t exist. Please tell me if I’m missing something. Case in point, $\sqrt{x} \sin x$ is not u.c. over $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Why is that counterintuitive? $f(x) = x$ is also uniformly continuous on $\Bbb R$ but has no limit at $\pm \infty$.

Comment: I see your point. I guess I'm trying to seek necessary and sufficient conditions for UC. For example, Weierstrass function is nowhere differentiable yet it is uniformly continuous over R.

Comment: I don't get your "case in point". $\sqrt{x\sin x}$ is not u.c. on $(0,\infty)$ because it's not even defined on $(0,\infty)$

Comment: @jjagmath: It was ${\sqrt x(sinx)}$ in the first version of this question, later changed to $\sqrt{x \sin x}$ by *someone else.* Perhaps OP meant $\sqrt x \cdot \sin x$ but we do not know for sure.

Comment: Yeah dont know how it got edited, but have corrected it now

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: @Rócherz Please, be careful when "improving" questions. You change the function by another one that makes no sense.

Answer (score -1):

Remember that continuity means that the limit of a function at a point is equal to its value at the point, in other words we can always "trap" the values of a function within a given range by choosing a small enough neighbourhood of inputs. One way to think about it is that if you give me a point $a$ and a height, I can always find a width such that I can draw a box of that size around $f(a)$ where all the values of $f(x)$ are inside that box.

Uniform continuity just means that you don't even need to tell me $a$ upfront - if you tell me the height of the box, I can pick a width and that box will work for *any* value in the domain of $f$. That's why $\sin x$ is uniformly continuous, because its periodicity and boundedness makes it easy to take something that works over $[0, 2 \pi]$ and apply it equally to any value. By comparison, $\sqrt{x} \sin x$  bounces up and down in ways that means a box that will fit the function around $x = 2 \pi$ will get overwhelmed at $x = 100 \pi$.

Comment: This answer is completely correct. However, I don't think it really addresses the op's confusions; they seem to believe that uniformly continuous functions must have all necessary limits